# loading required dojo files when button clicked

Tags: dojo

The application that I am developing now is loading 1200 dojo files that are related to application because of this page is taking 1 min to load, now I want to reduce its loading time.

All the 1200 files I don't require at the start point but require them when a button is clicked. Can any one suggest me how to load dojo file when a button is clicked instead of loading every file at once at the beginning.

Thanks in Advance looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading 1200 files you should probably take a look into the [Dojo Build System](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/), which should allow you to reduce the amount of files loaded.

Anyways, if you want to load files when a button is clicked, then you move the code that loads the module (`require()`) within the event handler? For example:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, on) {
  on(dom.byId("myId"), "click", function() {
    require(["module1", "module2"], function(module1, module2) {
      // Do stuff
    });
  });
});
```

Dojo will load the modules only once and return the same instance each time you request it, so there are no additional network requests of doing it this way.

But anyways, if you're loading 1200 files, then you have a problem and rather than looking how to lazily load those 1200 files, you should try to find out why it is loading 1200 files and eventually removing some dependencies.